# C++ Embed external .exe into my compiled .exe

Tags: c++, embed, exe, executable

I have a quick question on a topic that I'm quite a noob about. I have a program I made that sends a command to another .exe in a folder I called "tools". I send it in this format:

```
system("tools\\program.exe -r -w file.dat file_new.dat");
```

Everything works great, however, when I build my program into a .exe it will require the other executable to be in a second folder, obviously. Is there any way to include the external .exe into my project so the final product is just one .exe?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 (lol) and run windows 7 64bit.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, the management of external dependencies would be handled by the installer. [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) is my favoured solution for the Windows platform.

The alternative: Convert the binary to a base64 encoding and embed it as a header file in your project. When the application is run, convert the base64 representation of the exe to a binary sequence and then output that sequence of bytes to a file in a temporary directory (like C:\windows\temp or %AppData%\Local\Temp). Then run the exe. Once you're done with it, remove the exe.

Comment: So I would NEED to make an installer? I feel like there would be some way to add it as a resource or something. I want to be able to just send someone a single .exe file. I also don't want the user to be able to get a copy of the external .exe, this is why I want it embedded.

Comment: No, you don't need to, but the alternative is much more complex, NSIS produces a single exe which is fast and compressed

Comment: Would I need to have the user "install" my program to their system? If so, when it's installed, could they gain access to the external .exe. Because it is a .exe that I dont want anyone getting from me.

Comment: If the exe is not something you should be distributing, it doesn't matter if you're embedding in the installer or the core binary. Sorry if that's a pedantic answer but it's the truth

Comment: So are you saing that even if I put the my external .exe into my final project, someone could still get it?

Comment: Yep, cos you'll have to unpack it in order to run it.

Comment: Would it be possible to unpack it in a folder/place that they can't easily get access to? perhaps something with RAM? or a folder with certain permissions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30861/discussion-between-gearoid-murphy-and-user2356609)

Comment: @user2356609 If it is on their system and usable by your program they can get it. The only thing stopping them might be their skill level.

Comment: @GearoidMurphy: going the base64 approach is WAY overkill, not to mention a waste of memory and runtime processing. Just store the second .exe file as a binary resource inside the main .exe using an .rc file at compile-time.  At run-time, you can access it using `FindResource()`, `LoadResource()`, and `LockResource()`, and then write it out to a temp file on disk before passing it to `system()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the file to resources. And before the command is executed, you can check, if the second executable exists. If it doesn't exist, you have to extract the data from resource and store to the file...

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378011/why-are-loadresource-lockresource-sometimes-returning-concatenated-resource-data) was dealing with reading html from resource. It is very similar with binary file.